# Is the implementation of toLocaleTimeString() public? Is there somewhere I can see it?

Tags: javascript, v8

Im trying to find the implementation of toLocaleTimeString(). But I can't seem to find it.

I have looked in V8 code, in the ECMAScript documentation and I have had no luck. Maybe it is not public?

I found the following definition [here](https://tc39.es/ecma402/#sec-Date.prototype.toLocaleTimeString) , but not the actual code.

14.4.1Date.prototype.toLocaleString ( [ locales [ , options ] ] )

This definition supersedes the definition provided in ES2020, 20.3.4.39. 
When the toLocaleString method is called with optional arguments locales and options, the following steps are taken:

Let x be ? thisTimeValue(this value).
If x is NaN, return "Invalid Date".
Let options be ? ToDateTimeOptions(options, "any", "all").
Let dateFormat be ? Construct(%DateTimeFormat%, « locales, options »).
Return FormatDateTime(dateFormat, x).

Comment: You should be able to find it in the V8 code. Where exactly did you look? Did you find some other `Date` methods?

Comment: i think most things defer to ICU for this sort of thing

Comment: https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/src/objects/js-date-time-format.cc#L639

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Courtesy of Daniel White, I think this is the code for toLocaleTimeString: https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/3a0f407d266ec6429a166cf2ec5132f6558d3a51/src/objects/js-date-time-format.cc#L639